# How to replace field in group/sum if field is empty in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following expression:

```
@last_report = @all_reports.where(reporting_date: Report.select('MAX(reporting_date)'))
                                   .order(probability: :desc)
                                   .group(:probability, :reporting_date)
                                   .select("probability,
                                   SUM(proposals) AS proposals,
                                   SUM(amount) AS amount,
                                   SUM(amount_tp) AS amount_tp")
```

It could be that the field `amount_tp` in some records is empty. In this case it has to be replaced by `amount`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could do a `case`/`when`: `'SUM( CASE when amount_tp IS NULL THEN amount ELSE amount_tp')`

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: I use postgresql

Comment: Ok got it:  "SUM( CASE when amount_tp IS NULL OR amount_tp = 0 THEN amount ELSE amount_tp END) AS amount_tp" works for me as I just realized amount_tp could be also 0 (which is another case for replacement). I accepted @IgorDrozdov's solution because it is the solution to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql's `COALESCE` might be the function you're looking for. Here's the [tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/) for PostgreSQL

The usage looks like: `COALESCE(value,...)`, so the function returns the first non-NULL value:

```
@last_report = @all_reports.where(reporting_date: Report.select('MAX(reporting_date)'))
                                   .order(probability: :desc)
                                   .group(:probability, :reporting_date)
                                   .select("probability,
                                   SUM(proposals) AS proposals,
                                   SUM(amount) AS amount,
                                   SUM(COALESCE(amount_tp, amount)) AS amount_tp")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a neater way of doing it, but before your calculation try:

```
@last_report.each { |x| (x.update_attributes(amount_tp: x.amount) if x.amount_tp.nil? }
```

This will go through each report, and if the amount_tp is nil, assign it a value of whatever x.amount is. Then perform your method as above and any time the amount_tp attribute was nil, it will now equal the amount attribute